# Increase max daily votes?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, voting

**Preface:** A year on, after using more Stack Exchange sites, I'd like to now clarify: I'd like to see this only on Stack Overflow. It's quite easy to max out your votes on SO if you're on the site a lot. I don't have this problem on other SE sites.

---

I find myself using up all of my 40 votes/day very quickly... and not by just voting on any old crap.

There's just a lot of questions deserving of an up/down vote, posted daily... that and I spend too much time on SO.

Would you consider increasing this limit?

Comment: By voting this up, I have one less for all of the other questions... Well, did it anyways

Comment: Personally I don't need that much votes a day. But the vote limit could be increased for every 1k rep points.

Comment: @juergend A small amount of reputation is needed to cast votes, to discourage sockpuppetry. If we make an analogy (which admittedly is far from an *exact* analogy) to civics, this is like citizenship. To give some citizens more votes than others severely undercuts the democratic nature of a voting system. There is no good reason to do this.

Comment: @juergend nice suggestion!!!

Comment: @EliahKagan: The number of delete votes increases with rep too.

Comment: The number of flags increases with rep, too, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @juergend Flags and delete votes are different from upvotes and downvotes because flags and delete votes are *not* simply an expression of the user's opinion. When we disagree with someone's flagging or delete-voting, we're much more likely to say it's *wrong*. Upvoting and downvoting based on author identity is considered abuse; flagging or voting to delete is abusive in a hugely broader range of circumstances. The purpose of flagging and deleting is to *serve* the community,  not to *be represented* in it.

Comment: @EliahKagan I'd consider that a better answer than the only current one.

Comment: @EliahKagan Are you pro-asker equality?

Answer (score 26):

Query : `Select Count(*) From Users`

on running query on [data stackexchange](http://data.stackexchange.com) get the result **1694981** users, out of which:

> [image: hits maximum votes]

only 6000 users ever hit this limit, So I do not feel any valid reasons to increase the limit for now.

Comment: That's an interesting bit of data, in relation to this request. I think there are other objections to the idea that are more compelling, but +1 because I always like interesting, hard data inserted into things like this!

Comment: This can't be the main reason, can it? By this logic, any changes to 10k or mod tools would affect even fewer users, so should be immediately rejected.

Comment: @Geobits Even if there are more reasons, this is a strong enough logic. 10k+ users and mods participate much more actively, any changes to them would have great repercussion.

Comment: Awardees of Vox Populi also, by definition, participate actively. Oh, I'm sure some just hit it once for the badge, but...

Comment: 6000 at least once.  If the votes are log distributed, that's a crap ton of votes gone down the toilet.  Good thing it doesn't affect the voters since who cares if you can't upvote someone who helped you?  Costs nothing.  Too bad for all of the hard working answerers.

Comment: I think 6000 badge holders is explained by a psychological barrier that must be breached. Once you stop worrying about "lose points for downvotes", I find you need 3x the votes. I theorize the *Vox Populi* badge holders earned it around 20K to 40K. I stopped worrying about losing points around then. By the way, its up to 24876 in 2017.

Comment: As of today 31,868 [Vox Populi holder](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1108/vox-populi) out of 27+ (275,378*36) = 9,913,635 users from this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/users?page=275379&tab=reputation&filter=all)

Comment: This can happen when learning a new topic for many hours in a row.