# Daily review quota - how do users gain more?

Tags: support, review-queues, rate-limiting

I have noticed that there has to be some kind of *gain* on review quotas. I remember having my daily limit on **First Questions** being **40**, but today when I did some reviewing, I saw that my daily limit has increased to **80**.

Does it increase by the number of reviews you have done or by the queue size?

I'm a little skeptical if it is the number of reviews waiting in the queue because at the moment it was +10k which is pretty normal, I believe.

Comment: The change from 40 to 80 for first questions was announced [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/412063/2670892) and applies to everyone

Comment: I must have missed that, I also noticed that I'm not the only one having a limit of 80, seems like I've just overlooked it.

Comment: It's not normal to me at more than 500. That's why some changes have been made

Comment: I mean I agree, but *for me* it has been the "norm" because the queue has been so long for while now

Comment: "how do users gain more?" - oh how I wish that was a thing. Maybe we wouldn't be swimming in garbage if there were ways to actually get more reviews(/votes/flags/etc.). Randomly reminds me of the regenerative close vote FR (and while I can't find it, it's one proposed implementation of [another FR that will probably never be implemented](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285438/we-need-more-close-votes)).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The daily review quota [has recently been increased from 40 to 80](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/412063/51) for just the First Questions Review Queue, and only when the queue has more than 1000 items in it. We are going to play around with this setting to see how much of an effect it will have on queue size (might not be permanent).

Comment: Not sure if it is related, but the number of reviews in the Close Votes review seems to have dropped dramatically. Maybe people are just doing First Questions. I certainly run out of actual close votes if I try to do both.

Comment: @greg-449 I did not make any changes that would affect close votes (I think...)

Comment: @greg-449 Would that we could have separate piles of votes for each queue (and for organic question viewing), but I know that's a very complicated thing to even attempt.

Comment: I'm confused... well that's a normal state of being for me, but even more than usual. The way Yaakov phrased the answer to me indicates that there IS a separate pile of votes per queue.

Comment: I _think_ that each queue has its own pile of votes

Comment: If you actually vote to close that is taken from your daily limit of close votes which covers any close vote (in any queue or just voting on a question outside of the queues). I ran out after 32 reviews in the Close Votes review today because of close votes in the First Question queue.

Comment: @YaakovEllis *For science*, I used up 40 close votes from the close votes review queue, spent the other 10 between organically voting to close questions and First Questions. Now I can't vote to close from First Questions. I receive [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOlZr.png).

Comment: My confusion deepens. So you are allowed to do 80 reviews in first questions if it is really full... but can anyone really get that far if your total allowance is 50 (the 40+10 that Ian mentioned) votes anyway?

Comment: @Gimby Being under 3K has its advantages. We can spend 80 flags and still have 20 left ;)

Comment: 50 close votes is often not enough. It's certainly not enough to do 20 First Answers and 80 First Questions in a day without even thinking about the Close Votes queue. For this increase to 80 to be meaningful, something needs to budge on the close votes front.

Comment: I'd like to suggest a different limit, which isn't queue dependent as much a user dependent. Then a user can gain more daily review allowance with experience and instead of it being 20 in this queue and 40 in this other queue, that it's a 100 or 150 review limit across all queues. Then users can pick which queue or queues they want to spread those across.