# Was there some change in the First Questions queue?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, first-questions

The First Questions queue in Stack Overflow usually has several thousand items in it, and had a pretty consistent size since its inception (give or take a thousand or so). This morning I saw it drop to about thirty items.

While it's entirely possible a lot of users put in a concentrated effort to review all these items, it seems unlikely, and the history tab suggests that less than nine hundred items were reviewed today (at the time of posting).

Was there any change to the queue policy that made it shrink in such a dramatic fashion?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The backlog of reviews in the First questions review queue is increasing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411502/the-backlog-of-reviews-in-the-first-questions-review-queue-is-increasing) (specifically, Yaakov's answer describing the changes)