# Review Queue Dropdown Menu is becoming very slow (again)

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues

Some time ago, [I made a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411502/the-backlog-of-reviews-in-the-first-questions-review-queue-is-increasing/412063#comment871736_412063) about the (then) very slow response time of the review queue dropdown menu on Stack Overflow:

> There is also the issue (for me, at least) that, until I have
> 'fulfilled' my daily quota in FQ, the drop-down review menu from the
> top-bar takes a very long time (waiting in the three square dots
> timer) to actually present the menu. I assume this is because I have a
> lot of skipped posts in the queue, that have to filtered out.
> (Typically, 15-20 secs; one day, it went to 30 secs then just gave
> up.)

At that time, Yaakov Ellis asked me to report the issue in a separate post:

> @AdrianMole please post about that separately – Yaakov Ellis

However, by the time I had got round to doing that, the issue had gone away; I assumed that Yaakov and his team had done some of their magic and fixed the issue – so I didn't actually make that separate post.

But now, the issue seems to have come back, though not *yet* quite as severe – the "Square Dots" timer seems to last about 5-6 seconds, currently, but it seems to be getting longer each day, as the queue grows (currently, there are around 10,000 posts waiting for review in First Questions).

As I said in my original comment, my *guess* is that this has to do with the number of reviews I have skipped: looking at the difference in stats between a logged-on visit [to the stats page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/stats) for that queue (shows 9,879 for me) and an anonymous visit (10,020), I assume there are 141 questions in that queue that I have skipped (at the time of posting this).

Is this actually/still a known issue? Is my 'guess' as to the cause correct?

Comment: Any network requests that are left pending for too long?

Comment: @Oleg Not exactly sure what you mean, but the issue goes away (mostly) when I have completed 40 FQ reviews. Sometimes still a bit slow, but maybe that's skipped reviews I have in other (big) queues.

Comment: Not just you, it takes 5 seconds to load for me, and I haven't been doing any reviews.

Comment: @SamuelLiew Maybe just the raw size of the queue, then, not about skipped stuffs? Maybe there's some pre-filtering, even if no filter is manually selected. I quite often notice that the first bunch of reviews I get are C++ tagged, even though I haven't filtered for those.

Comment: Only takes a second for me, matches the amount of time the request takes. [Network requests on my browser](https://i.imgur.com/Q6JWzus.png)

Comment: I would suggest that @SamuelLiew goes off to fulfil his daily quota in FQ, then reports back on whether the UI speeds up. But, oh, wait a minute ... that "quota" would take quite a while to achieve. :)

Comment: @Adrian I was just wondering if it is network-related or script-related - it is odd that something like this would take up to 30 seconds - the only comparable load times I ever experienced here is when loading enourmous amount of posts when searching for questions. That is why my first hunch is to check the requests made to see if there is one that takes too much time to complete.

Comment: 10000 reviews isn't exactly something that should take *that* much time unless there is an issue with response time being very high for some reason (of course, something that needs investigation on SE's side)

Comment: @OlegValter I can't be 100% certain but, both now and previously, the issue **does** go away once the FQQ is no longer in my reach; and the delay definitely seems to increase in proportion to the size of that queue.

Comment: @Adrian yeah, that is likely related to the size of the queue -  just interested to find out what is the direct cause of the delay. Loads nearly instantly for me (no reviews today, but I do not have many skipped items either). Any suspects in the request timeline?

Comment: ... and, on the other sites on which I have review privs (Meta.SO and Meta.SE), the menu appears almost instantaneously using the same device and network. It's also reproducible on both my Laptop (Windows, Edge) and on my mobile (Android, Samsung Browser - no user-scripts running).

Comment: It does look like something about your (and, apparently, Samuel's) review activity is causing  the latency. Had any luck checking how long it takes for the server to respond to the request?

Comment: Looking for what Sam and I have in common but Oleg and Joundill don't ... all I can find is gold tag badges.

Comment: You can rule out gold tag badges. I don't have any but can reproduce the delay.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We were not able to reproduce the delays that are reported here. However, we were able to identify one slow-running query that runs when you click on the Review Queues toolbar icon (the query that determines how many items you have available to review in the First questions queue), and we have implemented some substantial improvements to its execution time (using myself as an example, went from 500ms to 50ms). I'm optimistic that this has resolved the issue. If you are still experiencing it, please let me know.

Comment: Well, today (and maybe yesterday?) I did notice a significant speed-up in the general response time. There still seems to be a distinct difference, though, once my daily FQ quota has been expended (or maybe even a stepwise improvement as I fulfil that quota for each 'big' queue). Thanks for your efforts.